# DataStage and SQL Server reporting

Tags: reporting, datastage

I need to find tools that can generate reports related to DataStage job and sequence. I would also need them for SQL Server Stored Procedure.

Any idea?

Comment: Update your question to be more specific. What is a report related to DataStage job? Provide OS and versions of the product etc.

Comment: In the toolbar of DataStage Designer there is a job report icon. This produces a report containing an image of the job design fully hyperlinked to descriptions of every stage in that design.  You can also produce a report from dsjob command.
I would imagine that a report about SQL Server stored procedure would best be obtained using SQL Server facilities. If, however, you have Information Governance Catalog (IGC), and have imported the stored procedure, you can produce a detailed report from IGC.

Answer (score 0):

In the toolbar of DataStage Designer there is a job report icon. This produces a report containing an image of the job design fully hyperlinked to descriptions of every stage in that design. You can also produce a report from dsjob command. I would imagine that a report about SQL Server stored procedure would best be obtained using SQL Server facilities. If, however, you have Information Governance Catalog (IGC), and have imported the stored procedure, you can produce a detailed report from IGC.